# VBA : Paste in Find command

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write the following Context using VBA.

When a specific word is selected in sheet 1, I want to find a specific word in sheet 2 and move it to that cell.

```
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cell.Find(What:=Apple, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End Sub
```

I want to put the word(Clipboard Paste?) to be copied instead of Apple, how can I do in this case ?

Comment: Use a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Clipboard. The idea of the Clipboard is to exchange data between Applications. Just write the content of the selected cell into an intermediate variable and use that as search term.

And never access the result of a Find-command directly. If `Find` fails to find something, it will return `Nothing`, you will get nasty runtime errors when you execute `Nothing.Activate`. Instead, assign the result of the Find to another variable and check if it contains something:

```
Dim searchTerm as String
searchTerm = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Dim hitRange as Range
Set hitRange = Cells.Find(What:=searchTerm, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not hitRange Is Nothing Then hitRange.Activate
```

A remark: Usually it's a bad idea to use `Select` and `Activate` in your code. I just left it there because I assume that the reason for your `Activate` is to show the result to the user. If you plan to do something else with the result, don't use `Activate`. Instead, work with the Range variable (`hitRange`).

Comment: Yes, you're right, corrected. It's still not perfect as it will fail if the activeCell contains an error, but I don't want to put the whole Excel VBA 101 into this answer...